# HQL NOT operator issue

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I want to translate the following mysql query to HQL

```
UPDATE `table` SET `my_bool` = NOT my_bool
```

And also I need to change only the row with the selected id

My attempt below

```
UPDATE Model m SET m.flag = NOT m.flag WHERE m.id is :id
```

```
function(Integer id){
     StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("UPDATE Model m SET m.flag = NOT m.flag WHERE m.id is :id");
     this.em.createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
}
```

I get the following error:

> unexpected token: NOT

I have just started learning HQL and the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3442) says it is a valid operator

> 11.6.9. NOT predicate operator
>
> The NOT operator is used to negate the predicate that follows it. If
>   that following predicate is true, the NOT resolves to false. If the
>   predicate is true, NOT resolves to false. If the predicate is unknown,
>   the NOT resolves to unknown as well.

Can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
UPDATE Model m SET m.flag = !m.flag WHERE m.id = :id
```

And C# code:

```
var query =  container.Resolve<ISession>().CreateQuery(hql);
query.SetParameter("id", 1);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: I made it working using em.createNativeQuery. Which version of hibernate are you using

Comment: I use .Net and NHibernate 4.0.3.4